# Batch File New Line in Compiling C program

Tags: c, batch-file

I am writing a program that many files and I write those in a batch file and compile that in MS Dos. I cannot write gcc command in multiple lines and this give me a huge line to scroll every time i need to edit something.
Can anyone help me to divide the gcc command in multiple lines?

This is how it looks.
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\gcc.exe -DWITH_OPENSSL -DWITH_DOM and so on.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^` as a line continuation character in batch files:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\gcc.exe ^
    -DWITH_OPENSSL ^
    -DWITH_DOM ^
    and so on.....
```

But you really ought to look at using a Makefile or similar instead.

Comment: .. or use an editor that supports wrapping lines. (But a makefile is still better.)